# VBA Excel Swapping values of ranges through temporary arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, move

I created a spreadsheet with some data and I want to swap places of ranges in that sheet through a macro.
Therefor I've created arrays of all the different ranges.

```
Dim C1G1, C1G2, C1G3, C1G4, C1G5, C1G6  As Variant

C1G1 = Range("A3:D3")

C1G2 = Range("A4:D4")

C1G3 = Range("A5:D5")

C1G4 = Range("A6:D6")

C1G5 = Range("A7:D7")

C1G6 = Range("A8:D8")


Dim C2G1, C2G2, C2G3, C2G4, C2G5, C2G6 As Variant

C2G1 = Range("E3:H3")

C2G2 = Range("E4:H4")

C2G3 = Range("E5:H5")

C2G4 = Range("E6:H6")

C2G5 = Range("E7:H7")

C2G6 = Range("E8:H8")

… etc.
```

Through input I ask (the value of) which range I want to swap with (the value of) another range in the spreadsheet. I use the variables from the input to put together the name of the arrays to be swapped. Example :  C2G4 (holding the value from Range("E6:H6")) to C5G3 (holding the value from Range("Q5:T5")

To be able to swap without overwriting the values of the arrays (and loosing the data)  I put the content of the arrays into 2 intermediate/temporary arrays and do the swap afterwards :

```
Dim IntermediateFrom As Variant

Dim IntermediateTo As Variant
```

When I try to put the values of the ‘from’ array into the intermediate arrays my code is taking the name of the array in stead of the content of the array. Same for the ‘to’ array.
When I try this statements :

```
IntermediateFrom = ("C" & SearchFromComb & "G" & SearchFromGetal)
```

The IntermediateFrom array has the stringvalue “C2G5” in stead of the content of the C2G5 array

`IntermediateTo = ("C" & SearchToComb & "G" & SearchToGetal)` : has the same problem

When I use :

```
IntermediateFrom = C2G4
```

the values of the arrays are copied well.
Same applies to :

```
IntermediateTo = C5G3
```

BUT I want to use substitution values to do the move.

Sorry for the extensive explanation but can someone help me out?

Comment: use an array of arrays where C and G are the two dimensions of the parent array and it holds an array in each item of the parent array.  Then you just need to refer to the correct item in the parent to bring in the child array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```vb
Dim ranges(1 To 2) As Range '<< your ranges of data
Dim tmp, rng1, rng2

'populate the array
Set ranges(1) = Range("A3:D8")
Set ranges(2) = Range("E3:H8")

Set rng1 = ranges(SearchFromComb).Rows(SearchFromGetal)
Set rng2 = ranges(SearchToComb).Rows(SearchToGetal)

tmp = rng2.Value
rng2.Value = rng1.Value
rng1.Value = tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to store the ranges, with the keys being C1G1, C1G2 etc.

In the following code some things have been hard coded but hopefully it demonstrates the idea.

```
Sub SwapRanges()
Dim dicRanges As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngOne As Range
Dim rngTwo As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim tmp As Variant

    Set dicRanges = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set rng = Range("A3:D3")
    For I = 1 To 2
        For J = 1 To 6
            Set dicRanges("C" & I & "G" & J) = rng.Offset(J - 1)
        Next J
        Set rng = Range("E3:H3")
    Next I
    
    
    Set rngOne = dicRanges("C1G1")
    tmp = rngOne.Value
    Set rngTwo = dicRanges("C2G5")
    rngOne.Value = rngTwo.Value
    rngTwo.Value = tmp
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The solution with the two dimensions array tested and it worked perfect.
Since I am not a VBA specialist I am not gonna try the dictionary solution.
Thanks a lot to all of you !!